# Omnifaces validateOrder BigDecimal cannot be cast to String when using p:ajax on two panel groups

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

**EDIT** How do I use o:validateOrder and p:ajax with two inputs not in the same panelGroup?

**ORIGINAL**

I'm getting java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String using Omnifaces o:validateOrder, but only for the case where I have my inputs over two panel groups and p:ajax processes two inputs. I am using two separate panel groups only for GUI layout. Debugging during o:validateOrder, the comparableValues array has one value as BigDecimal and the other as a string.

But when I have ajax process a single panelGroup that wraps both inputs(say `p:ajax process="bothLengthsPanelGroup")` things work and the comparableValues array has both values as BigDecimals.  But the GUI is doesn't have the layout I want. How can I keep my formatting but have p:ajax pass in BigDecimals?

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">    
 <h:panelGroup id="nlength">
    <p:outputLabel value="Bolt Length" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputLabel value="nominal:" />
        <p:inputText size="1" id="bolt_length" value="#{cc.attrs.bolt.nominal_fastener_length}">
            <p:ajax process="tlength nlength" update="nlength tlength boltFeedback" />
        </p:inputText>
  </h:panelGrid>
     <o:validateOrder type="gt" components="bolt_length thread_length" message="Nominal Thread Length must not exceed Nominal Bolt Length" disabled="#{empty cc.attrs.bolt.nominal_fastener_length and empty cc.attrs.bolt.nominal_thread_length}" />
 </h:panelGroup>

 <h:panelGroup id="tlength">
   <p:outputLabel value="Thread Length" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputLabel value="nominal:" />
        <p:inputText size="1" id="thread_length" value="#{cc.attrs.bolt.nominal_thread_length}">
            <p:ajax process="tlength nlength" update="tlength nlength boltFeedback" />
        </p:inputText>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <o:validateOrder type="gt" components="bolt_length thread_length" message="Nominal Thread Length must not exceed Nominal Bolt Length" disabled="#{empty cc.attrs.bolt.nominal_fastener_length and empty cc.attrs.bolt.nominal_thread_length}" />
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGrid>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just from looking at it why do you have two identical o:validateOrder components?  Why not have just 1 single o:validateOrder that lives outside both panelGrid's?  Another option is to wrap all of the above in one p:outputPanel with id="pnlLengths" and in your Ajax process="pnlLengths".  That will process both and the outputPanel is just a DIV so it should not affect your layout.

Comment: your second option is what I mentioned works (one ajax, one panel, etc) but then the layout isn't right.  I will try your suggestion of the div and see if I can match the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...I just use one o:validate order and change the process="pnlLengths" to process the whole DIV without affecting your panel grid layouts.

```
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="pnlLengths">
        <h:panelGroup id="nlength">
            <p:outputLabel value="Bolt Length" />
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel value="nominal:" />
                <p:inputText size="1" id="bolt_length" value="#{cc.attrs.bolt.nominal_fastener_length}">
                    <p:ajax process="pnlLengths" update="nlength tlength boltFeedback" />
                </p:inputText>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="tlength">
            <p:outputLabel value="Thread Length" />
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel value="nominal:" />
                <p:inputText size="1" id="thread_length" value="#{cc.attrs.bolt.nominal_thread_length}">
                    <p:ajax process="pnlLengths" update="tlength nlength boltFeedback" />
                </p:inputText>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <o:validateOrder type="gt" components="bolt_length thread_length" message="Nominal Thread Length must not exceed Nominal Bolt Length" disabled="#{empty cc.attrs.bolt.nominal_fastener_length and empty cc.attrs.bolt.nominal_thread_length}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: OK so this works, but the format isn't exactly the way it was.  I will post screenshot.  I feel I should have phrased my question differently as the Q is more how to use o:validate for inputs not within the same panel, while using p:ajax

Comment: From their example is different than yours though... http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateOrder  Have you tried moving the validateOrder OUTSIDE of the two panel grids?  Yours was placed inside the panel grids and duplicated?  I am wondering if that is what is causing your issue?

Comment: I updated my answer to remove the p:outputPanel and just use the outer PanelGrid as pnlLengths.  That should not affect your UI now as its exactly as it was before.

Comment: I think the validator has to be inside the tag that we are ajax processing (in your case pnlLengths) or else it is not triggered.  I moved the validator within one of the panel groups as to not create an extra empty cell and it works.  The caveat is that the id for the wrapping panelgrid houses other inputs (see screenshot) that the p:ajax now also processes, but I think it is a good tradeoff.

Comment: @jeff Updated my answer to reflect the o:validateorder inside the pnlLengths panelGrid!